# How can I set HTML's localStorage to an integer rather than string?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am having a problem using `localStorage` in a game I am trying to make. Also a not is the `money` variable is designed to increase by 1 every second. Here's some of my code:

```
var money = 0;
window.onload = function () {
    load();
    window.setInterval(save, 2500);
};
function save(){
    localStorage.setItem("money", money);
};
function load() {
    document.getElementById("moneyText").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("money");
};
```

My problem is that the `save` function is overriding the `money` variable every 2500 milliseconds. So I changed the `innerHtml` of the `moneyText` element to the same `localStorage` object like so:

```
function load() {
    document.getElementById("moneyText").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("money");
    money = localStorage.getItem("money");
};
```

Which does save the value. *However*, now when it increases it shows up like this:

```
01
011
0111
...
```

Where as before I added that line it showed up as this:

```
1
2
3
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The values in Local Storage are always a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2010892/2840103).

You could use [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) before you assign `money`.

```
 money = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem("money"));
```

Comment: Or `money = +localStorage.getItem("money")`

Comment: Or `money = Number(localStorage.getItem("money"))`.

Comment: Bro, you are a life saver thanks so much man!

Comment: Or `money = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("money"), 10)`.

Comment: @Xufox `parseInt` was my first thought, but OP may need a floating point number (even though it isn't implied by the question). These other suggestions are good, too.

Answer (score 2):

localStorage holds only strings. Use:

```
money = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem("money"));

localStorage.setItem("money", money.toString());
```